# How to extract chrome userdata and import to other PC

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, user-profiles

I would like to deploy chrome `userdata` that I set to my team.
I made `userdata` by using `--user-data-dir` option, and I set some setting values and chrome extensions.
After then, I tested on my other Windows PC.

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="D:\Chrome"
```

It worked well and all of setting and extensions worked.
So I deployed to my team, but some pc didn't work well.
There were no extensions and not adjusted settings.

I can understand that it doesn't work with different OS.
So I made `userdatas` for each OS.

But the problem is, not working in the same os and same version of chrome.
What should I do if I want to deploy chrome `userdata`?
I want that if some person executes the above command line, chrome that I did set starts.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a gmail account to sync your bookmarks,history and settings

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea too. But to adjust sync, the person has to do login with one chrome account. I don't want to make people perform anything. And if I do like that, every people have the same change if one person changed personal something.

Comment: @Jongkeun did you go through this link :https://smallbusiness.chron.com/export-chrome-profile-79321.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it.
It depends on real username, not be shown username.
I meant, you can check user real username in your user directory.
Even though your `userdata` is not in **User** directory, it was effected.
So if someone has username which it's the same to me, the guy's pc worked well.
But if it wasn't, it didn't work.